# rails-i18n translations not loading the exact data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n, ruby-1.8.7

I am using ruby 1.8.7 and i18n gem version 0.4.2 ,
In view page i have used

```
<h4><b><%= " #{t('date')} </b>:"%></h4>
```

and at en.yml

```
en: # locale
  net: "Net"
  amount_paid: "Paid Amount"
  date: "Date"
```

when i executed I got this

[image: snapshot]

Why I am not getting the exact translation

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look [here](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml), the `Rails-i18n` already has a `date` key defined that is overriding your definition. Try to change your `date` key or nested under another key:

```
en: # locale
  general:
   net: "Net"
   amount_paid: "Paid Amount"
   date: "Date"
```

Also note that the `"#{}"` in your view are not necessary:

```
<h4><b><%= t('general.date') </b>:"%></h4>
```

Comment: Now I got like " en-hd, general, date :  "

Comment: Where is the `en-hd` coming from? Did you create that locale?

Comment: Yeah , But I dont know how en-hd is getting.